# .htaccess redirect if file exists

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm looking to use .htaccess to redirect to one page or another based on if a file exists in the directory.

Basically I need all visitors to index.php to be sent to either home.php page if splash.php **does not** exist or splash.php page if splash.php **does** exist in the directory, so far i have this...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} index.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/splash.php -f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !splash.php
RewriteRule ^.*$ /splash.php [L]
```

This sends visitors to mysite.com/splash.php if it exists only if I specifically have mysite.com/index.php as my URL, it doesn't work if just use the  mysite.com URL.

I understand the first 3 lines of my code, but not the !splash.php -f bit (i got that from some other redirect code i found on SO).

How do i redirect to home.php if splash.php not present?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this rule. It should work on mysite.com/index.php, mysite.com/ or mysite.com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/splash.php -f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !splash.php
RewriteRule ^(index\.php|/|)$ /splash.php [L]
```

Comment: In there an extra `|` in your regex?

Comment: This works a dream mate, thanks! As long as i set DirectoryIndex = home.php

Comment: @Salman - the extra | is intentional (to also match an empty string)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to break it into multiple blocks, so try this (goes to splash.php if it exists, regardless of whether or not they have index.php in the file name, and then if splash doesn't exist goes to home.php):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/splash.php -f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !splash.php
RewriteRule ^.*$ /splash.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/splash.php !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /home.php [L]
```

Comment: This looks like it really should work, and i 'get it' now. But it just throws a 500 internal error

Comment: Ah, was probably missing a RewriteBase or other such setting.

Answer (score 0):

mate, I added a quick .htaccess and it works perfectly for me. I'm not sure what might be different in your configuration though. To avoid any confusion, here's the Apache (2) vhost that I'm using:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/test-setup"
   ServerName test-setup
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/lps-version-one_test-setup_error_log
   LogLevel warn
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/lps-version-one_test-setup_access_log combined
    <Directory "/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/test-setup">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All 
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I have both files in the directory, I'm redirected to splash.php (even though the name of the file in the url doesn't change - internally I'm redirected to splash.php). When I rename splash.php (or remove it) I only see index.php. When I put it back, the redirection works as normal. When I specifically put index.php in the url, with both files available, I'm redirected to splash.php.

Fwiw, one of the best things to remember about mod_rewrite is this:

> Despite the tons of examples and docs,
>   mod_rewrite is voodoo. Damned cool
>   voodoo, but still voodoo.
>   -- Brian Moore bem@news.cmc.net